# Asp.Net script in external js file

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

How can I use server-side script in an external js file to grab a reference to a dom element?

The following works as intended when used as inline-script, but is returning null when I move this to an external js file.

```
$("#<%= gridResults.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844970/is-there-a-better-way-to-get-clientids-into-external-js-files and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232465/how-to-use-jquery-select-element-by-id-and-asp-net-without-putting-ctl00-everyw/1232498#1232498 for a couple of general solutions to this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery/497872#497872 for a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to have an inline script block that creates a JavaScript variable.  This block should be added before your external JavaScript file.  Once you do this, you can reference that variable in your external JavaScript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var grid = $("#<%= gridResults.ClientID %>");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/my.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put `#<%= gridResults.ClientID %>`, because the gridresults.ClientID is specific to that asp.net page.

You could do:

```
<stript src="yourfile" type="text/javascript"> <!--link to external js file-->

<script type="text/javascript">
  var grid = $("#<%= gridResults.ClientID %>");

  yourfunction (grid);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you but a unique class on the grid using the CssClass property, you should be able to access the grid without having to know what it's clientID is.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to happen cannot. The external javascript file is not parsed by the ASP.NET page's code behind, so the functionality of ASP.NET is not available to it.