# UniqueID vs html element actual id

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating composite control, which has two other components that rely on each other.

In component A (image), I access component's B (input) UniqueID which equals

```
MyTextBox1$BoldTextBox
```

I use it in onclick JavaScript code...

But in rendered HTML input element has following id

```
MyTextBox1_BoldTextBox
```

So my javascript code , generated inside composite control has something like this:

```
onclick=$('#MyTextBox1$BoldTextBox').....
```

instead of:

```
onclick=$('#MyTextBox1_BoldTextBox').....
```

Could somebody please explain what is happening, and how can I reliably associate those two controls ?

Thanks , Paweł

Comment: You may find this SO thread useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500001/get-clientid-in-user-control-from-external-javascript-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `ClientID` property instead of the `UniqueID` property.

The reason for this is (sort of) explained on Atanas Korchev's blog post "[The difference between Id, ClientID, and UniqueID](http://blogs.telerik.com/AtanasKorchev/Posts/08-06-06/The_difference_between_ID_ClientID_and_UniqueID.aspx)".