# get ClientID for a specific user control bounded in a repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

iv'e got a list of user controls which i bind to a repeater .

**the user control : (Example) "AppProduct"**

```
       <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_details" runat="server" Text="Trigger" /> 
            <asp:HiddenField ID="pid" runat="server" value="5"/> 
       </div>
```

**the repeater :**

```
       <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <App:Product ID="P1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

**the problem :**

when i press a certain "btn_details" on a certain user control i need to call a javascript or Jquery function 
which does something according to the value of "pid" , but those are the Server Side id's 
how can i get the ClientID for these controls for the user control i clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a work around for this problem

first i set the repeater ClientIDMode:

```
       <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <App:Product ID="prd1" runat="server" />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

secondly i added a function to the btn_details on clientClick

```
        <asp:Button ID="btn_details" runat="server" Text="פרטים נוספים"  OnClientClick="Get_Product_Details(this);" />
```

in that function i extract the client id for the button and resolved the client id for the hidden field pid

```
         <asp:HiddenField ID="pid" runat="server" Value="5"/>
```

the function which will extract the client id //ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_Prd_2_pid_2:

```
          function Get_Product_Details(btn) {
//ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_Prd_2_btn_details_2
var s = btn.id;
var start = s.indexOf("btn_details");
var end = s.lastIndexOf("_");
sub = s.substring(start, end);
s = s.replace(sub, "pid");
var hidden = document.getElementById(s);
var id = hidden.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.0 set

```
 ClientIDMode = "Static"
```

For older .NET use

```
 '<%= Control.ClientID %>'
```

For your case

```
  function Get_Product_Details(uc) {
     var hidden_pid = uc.getElementById('<%= pid.ClientID %>');
  }
```

Comment: i'm sorry i need to change the question
the OnClientClick="Get_Product_Details(this);"

passes the button and not the entire user control like i meant

Answer (score 0):

Since a repeater can include multiple instances of your control, it will append a number to the ID to uniquely identify it. Use jQuery to find the other element relative to the button. [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using an hidden element for the pid on the button, you could instead attach the value via the jquery .data:

```
 private StringBuilder builder; 

 public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Repeater1.ItemDataBound += generateData;
     Repeater1.DataBound += outputGeneratedData;
     if (!Postback)
     {  
       List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
       // generate our data to bind
       Repeater1.DataSource = products;
       Repeater1.DataBind();
     }
 }
 // it is possible to do this inside the user control as well on page_load which would simplify it.
 public void generateData(objectSender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
      {
            // presumes your custom control is the first control in the repeater.. if not you can use FindControl to get the relevent controly
           MyUserControl ctl = (MyUserControl)e.item.Controls[0];
           // you could expose the buttons id in a property on the control but if prefered just use FindControl.
            builder.AppendFormat("$('{0}').data('PID','{1}');", ctl.FindControl('btn_details').ClientID ,((Product)e.item.DataItem).ProductID); 
      }
  }

  public void outputGeneratedData(object sender,Eventargs e)
  { 
        Response.Write(@"<script type='text/javascript'> + builder.ToString() + "</script>");
  }
```

an access it like this on though the client js item:

```
 function Get_Product_Details(item)
 { 
        var productId =  $(item).data('ProductID');
 }
```